# Vertical align text in child div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align the text in the `child` div to the bottom of the `parent` div box.

http://jsfiddle.net/sUS8D/

Can anyone assist?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Check out the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sUS8D/3/)

You need to adjust your CSS like this:

```
.parent {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    border: solid 1px;   
    position:relative;
}

.child {
    vertical-align:bottom;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have float and position on the same element?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
.child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I kind of prefer this one over complicated CSS hacks (Sarfraz - let's be honest, even if the dev looking at your code was born doing CSS would need to read it twice).

Of course, there are cross-browser implications. You decide whether you want to debug a two-liner or a jungle of CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

@Sarfraz got there first so my fix got saved as revision 4 http://jsfiddle.net/sUS8D/4/ (minus the float)